# Is a square a special case of a diamond (rhombus)?

Tags: geometry, terminology

> Is the diamond shape (rhombus) necessarily different from the square (sides not perpendicular, different lengths of the diagonals), or is the square a special case of a diamond?

Sometimes I see a square (with right angles) that is called a diamond just because of being rotated by 45 degrees from the position where two of the sides were horizontal and the other two vertical, but I doubt that just this rotation (which is an isometric transformation, without any deformation) is sufficient for the square to become another shape.

Comment: write your logical definitions of each then see which one also satisfies the other

Comment: At the end, the square is a special case of (nearly) any quadrilateral.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically speaking, something is called a rhombus, when it has four courners and all edges have the same length.

Something is called a square, when it has four courners, all edges have the same length and the four interior angles are $90°$.

So yes, a square **is** a special case of a rhombus.

Answer (score 0):

The [standard terminology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrilateral) in plane geometry (if the English language even has one) is that a square is a rhombus which is also a rectangle; equivalently, in a more exhotic and minimalistic way, a kite which is also a rectangle. Of course plane geometry is invariant by the action of the group of plane isometries, and therefore it isn't concerned with the graphical rendering of a square in an "organized" space where one or more directions are more important than the others.